# Cannot receive more than one touch in TouchMoved

Tags: c#, ios, mono, multi-touch, touches

I want to get the position of moving touches, so I need to get the array of touches which are moving in the **TouchesMoved**. I know how to get the array but the problem is that it only gets the one touch, and when I put more than one finger, it gives the first touch info only cause the array has one element only. it is demonstrated in the following code block:

```
public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
        Console.WriteLine(touches.Count);
    }
```

it always print 1. which means it only contains only one element.

Sincerely yours,
Peyman Mortazavi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself got it.

you need to enable multiple touch in the panel which is receiving touches.

lets suppose myPanel is the case.

```
myPanel.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
```

Regards,
S. Peyman Mortazavi